# React Apollo Client cache query without ID

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

I have some requests to the AniList API (https://graphql.anilist.co):

```
query Trending($page: Int, $perPage: Int) {
  Page(page: $page, perPage: $perPage) {
    media(sort: TRENDING_DESC) {
      id
      title {
        english
      }
    }
  }
}
query Popular($page: Int, $perPage: Int) {
  Page(page: $page, perPage: $perPage) {
    media(sort: POPULARITY_DESC) {
      id
      title {
        english
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And Apollo complaint that:

> Cache data may be lost when replacing the Page field of a Query object

Because Apollo doesn't know the different between Pages, they are overwritten.

My initial solution was to mark `Page` as a singleton:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Page: {
        keyFields: [],
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

This however does not work with pagination, as it will overwrite `"media({\"sort\":\"TRENDING_DESC\"})"` upon `fetchMore`

Here's a cache dump using `client.cache.extract()`:

```json
{
  "ROOT_QUERY": {
    "__typename": "Query",
    "Page({\"page\":1})": {
      "__ref": "Page:{}"
    }
  },
  "Page:{}": {
    "__typename": "Page",
    "media({\"sort\":\"TRENDING_DESC\"})": [{ "__ref": "Media:21" }],
    "media({\"sort\":\"POPULARITY_DESC\"})": []
  },
  "Media:21": {
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I satisfy the Apollo cache when querying `Page`?

Reference:

- https://anilist.co/graphiql
- https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs